# How to call multiple realms dynamically?

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-services

I need to call multiple realms on the basis of tenantname entered in browser. Right now we are doing is by creating different JSON files as per the tenant name. But i need to call keycloak.json directly from Keycloak server rather than putting dummy json.

Front-end using is Angular 7.

Comment: You want to open login page according to the realm name enter into the URL?

Comment: yes, i am entering https://localhost:4200/demorealm. So i have created one .json file into my angular code with demorealm.json which brings up the configuration and specific realm get loads up.

Below is the configuration for opening the login page.

{
  "realm": "demorealm",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "clientId": "singlespademo",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}

Comment: If you can change the design i can explain you how to achieve this without using any JSON file,we are doing something similar and loading things as per the realm provided by user.Code i cant share fully but give overlook of that as well.

Comment: Ya sure, please share me approach. Will look into it and figure out how to achieve it.

I can change the design basis on the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here the one solution which can be achieve with some changes in current design 
**First**
User will enter the url something like `https://<IP>:<PORT>/<GUI-PATH>?tenantId=<TenatID>`
Now in your Java Script code call a rest api which will give you the detail of `realmname/client-id` and other keycloak related information

Pass this information your keycloak.js adapter and `keycloak.js` will check all the details and redirect to login page as well.

Initialize Keycloak & bootstrap app

```
function loadApp(keyCloakObj) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.onload = function(){
            initiializeApp(keyCloakObj)
        }
        script.src = keycloakObj.url.split("auth")[0] + "auth/js/keycloak.js";
        script.onerror = function () {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.onload = function(){
                initiializeApp(keyCloakObj)
            }
            script.src = "app/auth/keycloak.js"
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        }
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
```

I just share basic code ,cant share full flow of code due to Copyright issue.